# php ajax contact form http_response_code() on line 17

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've tried to get this contact form to work, and I've followed the example http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form .  I only get the Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_response_code() in /hermes/bosoraweb183/b1669/ipg.tenkakletcom/spirit/mailer.php on line 17 above my contact form. I do not know php at all, but having this contact form is kick-ass! Here are the relevant files:

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="form-messages"></div>
                <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" required placeholder="Name...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">E-mail</label>
                                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn tf-btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

Here is the js file:

```
$(function() {

// Get the form.
var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });

});
```

});

and here is the mailer.php

```
<?php
// My modifications to mailer script from:
// http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
// Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
//            http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your     message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

I know this is not the best way of asking for help. But any help is much appreciated. If I could, I would, buy the person a coffee if it was physically possible :).

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you got PHP < 5.4.0 http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: also look at notes on given link, there a function for the lower php versions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PHP version is too old to support the http_response_code function.

I found this function posted in the comments page of the PHP manual, it may work for you.

```
function http_response_code($code = NULL) {
    if ($code !== NULL) {
        switch ($code) {
            case 100: $text = 'Continue'; break;
            case 101: $text = 'Switching Protocols'; break;
            case 200: $text = 'OK'; break;
            case 201: $text = 'Created'; break;
            case 202: $text = 'Accepted'; break;
            case 203: $text = 'Non-Authoritative Information'; break;
            case 204: $text = 'No Content'; break;
            case 205: $text = 'Reset Content'; break;
            case 206: $text = 'Partial Content'; break;
            case 300: $text = 'Multiple Choices'; break;
            case 301: $text = 'Moved Permanently'; break;
            case 302: $text = 'Moved Temporarily'; break;
            case 303: $text = 'See Other'; break;
            case 304: $text = 'Not Modified'; break;
            case 305: $text = 'Use Proxy'; break;
            case 400: $text = 'Bad Request'; break;
            case 401: $text = 'Unauthorized'; break;
            case 402: $text = 'Payment Required'; break;
            case 403: $text = 'Forbidden'; break;
            case 404: $text = 'Not Found'; break;
            case 405: $text = 'Method Not Allowed'; break;
            case 406: $text = 'Not Acceptable'; break;
            case 407: $text = 'Proxy Authentication Required'; break;
            case 408: $text = 'Request Time-out'; break;
            case 409: $text = 'Conflict'; break;
            case 410: $text = 'Gone'; break;
            case 411: $text = 'Length Required'; break;
            case 412: $text = 'Precondition Failed'; break;
            case 413: $text = 'Request Entity Too Large'; break;
            case 414: $text = 'Request-URI Too Large'; break;
            case 415: $text = 'Unsupported Media Type'; break;
            case 500: $text = 'Internal Server Error'; break;
            case 501: $text = 'Not Implemented'; break;
            case 502: $text = 'Bad Gateway'; break;
            case 503: $text = 'Service Unavailable'; break;
            case 504: $text = 'Gateway Time-out'; break;
            case 505: $text = 'HTTP Version not supported'; break;
            default:
                exit('Unknown http status code "' . htmlentities($code) . '"'); break;
        }

        $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');
        header($protocol . ' ' . $code . ' ' . $text);
        $GLOBALS['http_response_code'] = $code;
    } else {
        $code = (isset($GLOBALS['http_response_code']) ? $GLOBALS['http_response_code'] : 200);
    }
    return $code;
}
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#107261)

Comment: I actually in a fit of rage, deleted the http response codes, I just need to make the email show in the contact e-mail. yes I got it to work, thanks so very much guys! Rest assured you'll have a great week from helping a guy in need ;).

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, your Php version is not compatible. If you want to make your code work, simply comment the line wherever `http_response_code()` function is used and it will work like a charm.

All the best learning Php.